# Как открыть ссылку в новой вкладке IE?

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer

Добрый день. Есть необходимость программно открывать некоторые URL-адреса именно Internet Explorer'ом. Пробовал через **ShellExecute** и OLE-обьект **InternetExplorer.Application**, IE запускается все норм. Но одна проблемка каждый раз запускается новая копия iexplore.exe, а хотелось бы, если есть запушенная копия, то открывать ссылку в новой вкладке. Кто, что может посоветовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем испробовав несколько методов остановился на следующем:
Подключаем модуль **ShDocVw** (у меня **SHDocVw_TLB**) и **OLEAuto**.
Обьявляем глобальную переменную **IE: IWebBrowser2**.
Функция открытия URL через IE получилась такая:

```
procedure OpenInternetExplorer( sURL : string );
var   Flags: Olevariant; //Переменная в которой будем устанавливать 
                         //параметры открытия ссылки
begin
  Flags := $0800;        //Из MSDN navOpenInNewTab = 0x0800
  if IE=nil then         //Если не запускали IE, запускаем
    begin
      IE:=CoCppInternetExplorer.Create;//Если подключали ShDocVw то нужно так
                                       //CoInternetExplorer.Create;
      IE.Visible:=True;
      IE.Navigate(sURL,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam);
    end
  else
    begin                //Если уже запущен, открываем УРЛ 
                         //с параметрами создания новой вкладки
      IE.Navigate(sURL,Flags,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam);
    end;
end;
```

Использование процедуры

```
OpenInternetExplorer('http://ya.ru');
```

Как-то так, если есть какие либо дополнения буду очень признателен:)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ссылка открывалась в текущей вкладке.

```
uses
  Windows, OLEAuto;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  public
    IE: OleVAriant;
    procedure OpenInternetExplorer( sURL : string );
    procedure CLick;
end;

var
 Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.OpenInternetExplorer( sURL : string );
const
  csOLEObjName = 'InternetExplorer.Application';
var
  WinHanlde: HWnd;
begin
  if VarIsEmpty(IE) then
  begin
    IE := CreateOleObject(csOLEObjName);
    IE.Visible := true;
    IE.Navigate(sURL);
  end
  else
  begin
    WinHanlde := FindWIndow('IEFrame', nil);
    if 0 <> WinHanlde then
    begin
      IE.Navigate(sURL);
      SetForegroundWindow(WinHanlde);
    end
    else
    begin
      // handle error ...
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Click( sURL : string );
begin
  OpenInternetExplorer('microsoft.com');
end.
```

Можно поковыряться в [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us/windows/ie?query=internet%2Bexplorer&refinement=61&ac=8) и попробовать найти остальные методы

Comment: Пробовал использовать точно такую же процедуру, и все равно открывается новое окно IE :(

Comment: вы внимательно посмотрите, где в моем примере описана переменная IE: OleVAriant. Она здесь общая для всего приложения. А вы, наверняка, описали ее локально, и при каждом вызове процедуры у вас появляется новый экземпляр этой переменной.

Comment: Переменную IE: OleVAriant делал глобальной. Наблюдается следующая поблема: новых окон уже не создается, но и новых вкладок тоже, обновляется текущая вкладка на новый URL. Сейчас хочу попробовать через IE: IWebBrowser2 и его метод Navigate, побалуюсь с его параметрами.